# how to erase the lines i drew on a UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cgcontext

I create a UIView and put it on top of an imageView,and set the uiview's background color as clearcolor,all the drawing take place on that UIView,how can just erase the line I drew on that uiview ?
thanks.

Comment: How did you add the drawing to the view specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear)` and then draw the area you want to erase. Clearing the context with `CGContextClearRect` can be used too if you want to clear the whole screen (or a rectangular part of it).

Answer (score 0):

call setNeedsDisplay on your view and next time drawRect dont draw the lines but just fill the whole bounds with clearColor